# Checking for existing entry before inserting data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

I am trying to insert new clients only if they don't already exist.  I am having problems I think with the SQL statement, but I wanted to give context in the PHP too:

```
   $sql = "INSERT INTO clients
        (`studentEmail`, `studentPassword`, `parentEmail`, `parentPassword`,
        `studentFirstName`, `studentLastName`, `studentPhone`, `parentFirstName`,
        `parentLastName`, `parentPhone`, `school`)
         VALUES ('$studentEmail', '$studentPassword', '$parentEmail',
        '$parentPassword', '$studentFirstName', '$studentLastName',
        '$studentPhone', '$parentFirstName', '$parentLastName', '$parentPhone', '$school')
        SELECT studentEmail
        FROM clients
        WHERE not exists (select * from clients where studentEmail == '"$studentEmail"')";
```

Comment: Are you getting a specific error?

Comment: You need to escape your values. Read about [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: @Xeoncross: you know **nothing** about how the variables were processed before used in this query

Comment: Whats with the use of ` instead of '?

Comment: I have escaped the values, I was just trying to trim down the post

Comment: @Matthew PK: come on, guys, why do you think so? You don't see `mysql_real_escape_string` but who told you it hasn't been used in previous lines?

Comment: @zerkms, true, but he obviously isn't using prepared statements which is a big no-no right there.

Comment: @MalcolmO'Hare I guess this is MySQL, it is how you quote object names with it

Comment: @Xeoncross: "I have escaped the values, I was just trying to trim down the post", obviously he has escaped them. Don't even start discussion about no-no yes-yes and escaping vs prepared statements, it is offtop

Comment: @zerkms, it's not a big deal. As you can see, he hadn't posted that comment yet. Although as sensitive as you seem to be about all this it sounds like you've had a *talking too* before. :)

Comment: @Xeoncross: no, it just becomes a bit annoying when in each topic there are 90% comments about mentioning about sql injections instead of answering to actual question (and in a lot of cases, like this one, OP **knows** about them and just didn't want to post bloating lines)

Comment: @zerkms, very true. SO does have a problem with things like this. However, in this case we have a real problem with radley. He doesn't even know you can insert values into double quotes. Look at this question 1) he is using mysql instead of mysqli or PDO. 2) he doesn't know about A) running a simple select or B) REPLACE INTO before he tries an insert. My point is just that in this case, he is the perfect candidate for my comment above since there is a high probability he doesn't know what he is doing.

Comment: @zerkms I didn't post an answer I posted a comment. And he didn't mention escaping them until after I made my comment.

Comment: @Matthew PK: obviously he didn't mention that he has php and mysql installed either. So let give him advices how to install php and mysql in best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check whether the email exists before inserting the data.

```
$check = mysql_query("SELECT studentEmail FROM clients WHERE  studentEmail = '{$studentEmail}';");

if (mysql_num_rows($check) == 0) {
    // insert
}
```

Comment: I tried this method first, because php will fit in nicely with the rest of the framework.  After added concatenation (.$studentEmail.), I am getting the error "mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not valid MYSQL result resource in..."Any ideas?

Comment: This query works, but I am still getting the error: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument.  
    SELECT studentEmail FROM clients WHERE  studentEmail = '{$studentEmail}';  It says the error is happening on this line:  "if (mysql_num_rows($check) == 0) {"

Comment: That's weird! Does the `$check` return the query result?

Comment: I'm having a hard time finding out because this is a processing page, so even if i echo anything, nothing would display on the screen.  My js points at this page.

Comment: You can just point the browser at the php file and see the output,can't you? :)

Comment: Here is what i have now:  $check = mysql_query("SELECT studentEmail FROM clients WHERE  studentEmail == '".$studentEmail."';");
 $num = mysql_num_rows($check);


 if (($num) == 0) { /*PROCESS*/ }
ELSE {echo "FAIL";}

Comment: you didn't concatenate, so $studentEmail wouldn't work...isn't that all i changed?

Comment: You don't need to concatenate if it's in double quotes. Double quotes parse variables inside them.

Comment: You were right!  It didn't need any changing.  Thanks for hanging in there with me!

Answer (score 3):

In an insert statement, `select` and `values` are mutually exclusive.  Instead of:

```
insert table1 (col1, col2, col3, ...)
values (1, 2, 3, ...)
select col1
where  not exists (...)
```

Try:

```
insert table1 (col1, col2, col3, ...)
select 1, 2, 3, ...
where  not exists (...)
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I'm trying the php approach first.

Comment: I'm trying this, but i keep getting an SQL error...here is my updated code: INSERT clients (`studentEmail`, `studentPassword`, `parentEmail`, `parentPassword`,
     `studentFirstName`, `studentLastName`, `studentPhone`, `parentFirstName`,
     `parentLastName`, `parentPhone`, `school`)
    SELECT '$studentEmail', '$studentPassword', '$parentEmail',
     '$parentPassword', '$studentFirstName', '$studentLastName',
     '$studentPhone', '$parentFirstName', '$parentLastName', '$parentPhone', '$school'
    WHERE not exists (select studentEmail from clients where studentEmail = '{$studentEmail}');

Comment: Even though I chose the other method, I'd still like to know why I can't get this to work.  Database query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds...to use near 'WHERE not exists (select studentEmail from clients where studentEmail = 'robins.' at line 7...the email address I am using is robins.br@gmail.com

Comment: Try `insert into` instead of `insert`?

Comment: No change with insert into.  I also tried: studentEmail = '"$studentEmail"'

Comment: Looks good to me, perhaps check the SQL as it gets send to the database?

Comment: would the period in "robins.br@gmail.com" cause any problems?  everything should be escaped at this point.  I'll put some actual values in later and check (gotta get some work done now).  I'll try to update this post this evening.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `MERGE` statement:

```
merge into clients on (select 1 from clients where studentEmail = blabla)
when not matched then insert blabla
```

(the merge statement syntax will vary according to your RDBMS, so look at the doc for your particular RDBMS implementation)

Comment: unfortunately mysql doesn't support `MERGE`. But it does support `REPLACE` and `INSERT ... ON DUPLIcATE KEY UPDATE`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a unique index on the email field, then you can just do `INSERT IGNORE ...` and inserts corresponding to existing emails will be quietly discarded.